# Configurable product is not editable in backend after configurable p. upload with Magmi,

Tags: magento, backend, magmi, configurable

I uploaded configurable products in Magmi, now the configurable product is not editable in backend under Manage Products.
It shows only the menu points over the entire screen but nothing else.

The simple products can be edited

I have been trying to solve this for 3 days so far. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When the admin page for a product doesn't load completely, that means there's most likely an exception (error) being thrown.  Check your var/logs folder for errors logs.